# ASP MVC Setup problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had a website running fine. One day i decided to revisit the site and discovered that it is not functioning any longer. First i thought it has to do with the provider (but to be honest i didn't get a clear answer). 
I 'm  banging my head against the wall: i get the following error:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Requested URL   http://www.mywebsite.com:80/UrlRouting.axd

Where does this come from? This worked fine!

EDIT
I have the ability to set in the Extensions the ASP.NET combo between 2.0 and 2.0 integrated pipeline. When setting to 2.0 only i get the first (welcome) page  as it should be. But as soon as i select an item that has a link e.g.

http://www.mywebsite.com/Communication/Index

i now get this error:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Are you sure its a ASP.NET MVC project? the UrlRouting.axd is generally used for routing on ASP.NET WebForms projects.

Comment: Yes i 'm sure it 's a MVC project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty embarrassing...it turns out that this was a problem at the hosters side. They did justify something and it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you have any resources on the page (Javascript files etc...) that depend on a Web address that may no longer be available.  An example of something that may be the culprit would look like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i do use such kind of resources but they seem to work properly (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js)